# when Comparing two Version numbers what does vnum1=vnum1*10 do

Tags: c++, string

```
        vnum1 = vnum1 * 10 + (v1[i] - '0');
```

I understand that (v1[i] - '0') converts a string to integer but what does vnum1*10 achieve?

Comment: `v1[i] - ‘0’` does **not** convert a string to integer. It converts a **character** in the range `’0’..’9’` to the digit that it represents. The code that you’ve posted, in an appropriate loop, would convert a string to an integer.

Comment: Multiplying by 10 shifts the existing number left by 1 digit, [*My Hero Zero* by Schoolhouse Rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxYsgRsNg2s).

Answer (score 2):

This is no comparison, it's *assignment*.

What this line does is:

1. First, multiply value of `vnum1` by `10`
2. Then, add value of digit stored at position `i` in `v1`
3. Finally, assign the result to `vnum1`.

From this little context, I can guess this is an implementation of [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (though `std::stoi` is much safer to use).